# setText after DatePickerDialog using local date format

Tags: android, date, locale, date-formatting

In my Android Studio project I have a DatePickerDialog.
On the onDateSet, I have 3 arguments :

- int selectedYear;
- int selectedMonth;
- int selectedDay;

I would like to make a setText using the local format of the device.

For exemple, in USA the date is like : **mm/dd/yyyy**, but in France it's like **dd-mm-yyyy**

How can I do that ?

This is my code :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog datePicker;
    datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int selectYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
                textViewDate.setText("HERE I HAVE TO PUT THE DATE WITH THE LOCAL FORMAT);
            }
        }, year, month, day);
        datePicker.show();
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use this methods:

```
public String formatDateStyles(Date date, Locale currentLocale) {

    String result = "";
    DateFormat formatter;

    int[] styles = { DateFormat.DEFAULT, DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.MEDIUM, DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.FULL };

    for (int k = 0; k < styles.length; k++) {
      formatter = DateFormat.getDateInstance(styles[k], currentLocale);
      result = formatter.format(date);
    }

    return result;
  }

public Date getDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return cal.getTime();
    }
```

by this way:

```
textViewDate.setText(formatDateStyles(getDate(selectYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay), new Locale("en", "US")));
```

More details [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/DateFormatwithLocale.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int selectYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            DataFormat dateFormat= android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
            cal.set(selectYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay)
            textViewDate.setText(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
        }
```